# How to access Sim Card Info On Android API levels less than 21

Tags: android, sms

I'm new to android Programming.

I know that I can't access sim info such as subscription_id
using classes like TelephonyManger or SMSManager under API level 21.

I also know that I could iterate throgh all SMS's and find different subscription id's but
in some cases that causes problems.

How do apps like GO SMS find out which sim number has sent or received SMS?

Is there any way to obtain information about Sim, on API 19?

or Any idea how to implement this feature on these platforms?

Comment: share what you have reach till now and your code

Comment: Please share what did you end up doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a very long time but I post this so that it might help someone:

Unfortunately ,

On Android API levels less than 21, there is no direct and official way to determine which SIM card has sent or received an SMS message. The ability to retrieve the SIM card information associated with an SMS message was introduced in Android API level 21 and above.

Before API level 21, the SMS API did not provide a specific method to identify the SIM card for sent or received messages. You could only obtain the sender or recipient phone number, but not the SIM card information.

But there are unofficial ways to achieve this which are not consistent cross device manufacturers and therefore I don't bother mentioning them here.